# Reverse Screen Share: Mac Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, remote-desktop

I am currently enjoying the powerful features of screen sharing. I was wondering though, if it would be possible to share my screen with another Mac. I have a Macbook Pro that can connect to a Mac mini (which in its turn is connected to a flatscreen). Is this possible and what must I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is as part of OSX Screen Sharing

In the machine whose screen is to be shared. Check that in System Preferences->Sharing Screen Sharing or Remote Management is on

On the machine that is to display the screen run /System/Library/CoreServices/Screen Sharing.app and enter the remote machine name or in Finder go go to server vnc://reomote macine ip address

Comment: I think vnc:// would work better ;)

Comment: And you can also go to the finder and it will show up there and you can click on it and choose "Share Screen"